# Python asyncio with threads

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a bit of an unique situation. There are two coroutine calls thats I need make, lets call them A() and B(). It's important that I don't spend more time on these two calls than what A() would take, but both need to run concurrently.

The idea I have here is to create two threads T1 and T2. Run the coroutine A() in T1 and couroutine B() in T2. This way they run concurrently, but is there a way for me to interrupt T2 as soon as T1 is complete to satisfy t(B) <= t(A)?

Comment: No, this is a hopeless design.  Threads and asyncio are not really friends.  And remember that coroutines do not actually run concurrently.  They are sharing the CPU.

Comment: @TimRoberts Well, threads are also sharing a CPU if there's only one CPU available, it's just that they're scheduled by the OS, not cooperatively by themselves... (Really, _nothing_ runs concurrently on a single processor, after all... :-) )

Comment: @TimRoberts coroutines do run concurrently.

Comment: @AKX Don't we call them (Tasks and Threads) "concurrently" ? As opposed to "in parallel"

Comment: @S.B Only if you define the term very carefully.  On a machine with multiple CPUs, which virtually all of us are using now. there CAN be two threads running at the exact same time.  There can never be two coroutines executing at the exact same time.

Comment: @TimRoberts Without multiprocessing there can't be two threads running at the exact same time because of the GIL. But we still call it "concurrently". Concurrently in Python doesn't mean that at an exact moment two threads are running simultaneously.

Comment: To make it clear one these are IO bound workflows and I'll create an event loop for each thread. So these calls A() and B() are running in different threads on their own event loops. I just want to make sure B() can be terminated as soon as A() completes.

Comment: it's funny how people's definitions of what's running concurrently and what's not change when you are calling into external C code.

Comment: @S.B -- You're making up your own definitions.  There is a clear difference between threads and coroutines in the way they execute.

Comment: @nebula186 is there a reason why they have to be two eventloops ? can they just be 1 eventloop ? or is 2 eventloops a requirement for something other than performance ? a single eventloop can run 2 IO operations concurrently.

Comment: @TimRoberts Of course. I didn't say otherwise. I just said they are in the same category, one cooperative and one preemptive. Nevermind.

Comment: @AhmedAEK missed a word in the previous comment. "One of these are IO bound" and the other is CPU bound. Which is why I need the use of threads unfortunately.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Even the [asyncio docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) call asyncio concurrent. "asyncio is a library to write **concurrent** code using the async/await syntax." "Concurrent" really is used how S.B. is using it.

Comment: @user2357112: That said, they can only truly run concurrently when they're doing meaningful async I/O can that can be executed asynchronously. If you have two CPU-bound tasks, it's never going to be truly concurrent, but if each task asks for data from some data source that can use async I/O (e.g. disk, network, subprocess), then the tasks waiting on I/O can release the event loop to do other useful work. Amusingly, CPython's GIL means it runs pretty much the same way (ignoring the possibility of C extensions that manually release the GIL), since only one CPU-bound thread can run there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to mix coroutines and threads.

Instead, it sounds like you want to wrap the coros into [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task)s, then await for [`asyncio.wait([a_task, b_task], return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait), and cancel the B task.

Answer (score 0):

if you must run two loops concurrently, then you can run each loop in a different thread, but stopping an eventloop will only stop an async function if the eventloop was waiting, it will not stop an async function if it was not waiting, you cannot stop the function if the function is doing a computation.

the following code creates 2 eventloops, one to run `b` and one to run `a`, and when the loop that runs `a` is done, it stops the loop running coroutine `b`, which raises a `RuntimeError` that is caught, **this code is really Dangerous, use at your own risk**.

```py
import asyncio
import threading

async def a():
    print("start A")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("done A")

async def b():
    print("start B")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("done B")

def run_function_in_loop(loop, func):
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(func())
    except RuntimeError:
        print("task B cancelled")

def main():
    loop1 = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    thread_b = threading.Thread(target=run_function_in_loop, args=(loop1, b,), 
                                daemon=True)
    thread_b.start()
    
    loop2 = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop2.run_until_complete(a())
    
    if loop1.is_running():
        loop1.call_soon_threadsafe(loop1.stop)
        thread_b.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

note that replacing `asyncio.sleep` with `time.sleep` causes task `b` to not stop, as you cannot stop a task that's not waiting.

---

if `b` is doing a computation and you must stop it, then you need to spawn a child process and kill it when `a` is done if `b` wasn't done yet, **the next code is safer**.

```py
import asyncio
import time
import multiprocessing

async def a():
    print("start A")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("done A")

def b():  # CPU bound
    print("start B")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("done B")

def main():
    pool_b = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
    future_b = pool_b.apply_async(b)

    loop2 = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop2.run_until_complete(a())
    if not future_b.ready():
        pool_b.terminate()
        print("task B cancelled")
        return_b = None
    else:
        return_b = future_b.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't think the OP really wants to run 2 asyncio loops - it is more like a XY problem. 

An example with `run_in_executor` maybe could be of more use here.

Comment: @jsbueno you cannot kill a tasks being run by `run_in_executor`, cancelling the "task" only stops whoever is waiting on it, it doesn't stop the working thread/process from completing the task, the above code is the one safe way to cancel a running computation task.

Comment: no, of course -that would need a queue thing to send the task a message for it to kill itself.